# How to deal with 2 almost identical tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of baseball stats, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE batting_stats(
    ab                INTEGER,
    pa                INTEGER,
    r                 INTEGER,
    h                 INTEGER,
    hr                INTEGER,
    rbi               INTEGER,
    playerID          INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(playerID) REFERENCES player(playerID)
);
```

But then I have a table of stats that are basically exactly the same, but for a team:

```
CREATE TABLE team_batting_stats(
    ab                INTEGER,
    pa                INTEGER,
    r                 INTEGER,
    h                 INTEGER,
    hr                INTEGER,
    rbi               INTEGER,
    teamID            INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(teamID) REFERENCES team(teamID)
);
```

My first instinct is to scrap the Foreign key and generalize the ID, but I still have a problem, I have these 2 tables, and they can't have overlapping IDs:

```
CREATE TABLE player(
    playerID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname   TEXT,
    lastname    TEXT,
    number      INTEGER,
    teamID      INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(teamID) REFERENCES team(teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE team(
    teamID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    city        TEXT,
);
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious that could solve this problem and reduce stats to a single table.

Comment: Why is reducing it to a single table preferable? Seems like separate tables is the way to go.  You might want to think about adding in a season FK, though.  Seems like you need a season join table for player and team, then use the player/season key as the FK in the stats table.

Comment: if the players do not move from one team to another, you can remove team_batting_stats altogether. Then use a sum() Select statement on batting_stats INNER JOIN player ON batting_stats.playerID = player.playerID GROUP BY player.teamID to get the statistics for the whole team

Comment: I have these functions like: save_player that are pretty hairy, that could be re-used to do save_team.  It would mean a lot of code reduction in my application.  There is also a `pitching_stats` and `team_pitching_stats` table that could be combined.

Comment: Oh, the players will definitely move around between teams, that's half the fun.

Comment: I was thinking about seasons as well, you are right @tvanfosson.

Comment: @cha is right about calculating the averages per team. You'd only need the table if you want to cache them so you don't have to recalculate them every time. I guess I was assuming that as it would be pretty time consuming to show, say, the last 10 years of team batting average.

Comment: I expect there will be many trades throughout a season, but a team would only be interested in its own players while they were on the team, not a sum of all its current players.  There is situational logic in the game that will affect individual player stats, such that a player on one team could perform better than on another (perhaps better or worse team).

Comment: if you have an app that is relying on team_batting_stats, then you can replace it with a view I have suggested above. Otherwise, drop it. Having the same information repeating in many places and keeping it in sync is a shortcut to failure

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the "same" information.  If a player gets 5 hits on one team, gets traded and 5 hits on another team, this should not count as ten hits for his current team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce the stats to a single table, you can add a couple of relationship tables to link either a batter or a team to the stats table.

Entity tables:

```
CREATE TABLE stats(
    statsID          INTEGER primary key,
    ab                INTEGER,
    pa                INTEGER,
    r                 INTEGER,
    h                 INTEGER,
    hr                INTEGER,
    rbi               INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE player(
    playerID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname   TEXT,
    lastname    TEXT,
    number      INTEGER,
    teamID      INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(teamID) REFERENCES team(teamID)
);

CREATE TABLE team(
    teamID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    city        TEXT,
);
```

Relationship tables that link batters/ teams to stats:

```
CREATE TABLE batting_stats(
    playerID integer not null REFERENCES player(playerID),
    statsID integer not null REFERENCES stats(statsID),
    primary key (playerID, statsID)
);

CREATE TABLE team_batting_stats(
    teamID integer not null REFERENCES team(teamID),
    statsID integer not null REFERENCES stats(statsID),
    primary key (teamID, statsID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to revisit the structure of your data and what (and how) you are trying to capture the data. There is a differance if the teams are "permenant" like a major league club or temporary like a little league team. The former is easlier than the latter but a solution for the latter would also work for the former.

You also need to decide how normalised you want to keep your data - if you know which batter faced which pitcher than the pitchers stats can be derived from the batting stats but this is probably waaay more compolicated than it is worth.

The atomic items are the player, the team and the game. Trades will happen but I am guessing that they do not happen between the 6th and 7th innings. So the game is the link between teams and players.

So you get tables like:

```
PlayerID   Name    Dog's Name
   1       Fred     Fluffy
   2       Joe      Spike

TeamID    Name      Mascot
   1      Chicago   Comets
   2      Timbuktu  Pussy Cats

GameID    Date        Location     Season
   1      2012-18-12  Over there    2012
   2      2011-20-4   The Park      2011

GameID    PlayerID   TeamID     AllTheStatsFromThisPlayerAtThisGame
   1         1          1
   1         2          2
```

The player stats are the collection from all games he played.
The team stats are the collection of all players in the team for all games.